# Are there [other] examples of Chinese police directly arresting opposition figures abroad?

Tags: china, police, extraterritoriality

[According](https://safeguarddefenders.com/en/blog/chinese-police-kidnaps-writer-mongolia) to Safeguard Defenders (NGO):

> Last month [May 2023], Chinese police descended on the home of historian and activist Lhamjab Borjigin and arrested him. Such arrests are commonplace in the authoritarian country, but his capture did not happen on Chinese soil. It took place in a foreign country – Mongolia.
>
> Chinese police, with Borjigin’s daughter in tow, arrived at his apartment in Ulaanbaatar on 3 May and forcibly took the 80-year-old back to China, according to a close friend of his who lives in the Mongolian capital.
>
> [...] The involuntary return of Borjigin is an example of a Type 3 involuntary return, where Chinese police kidnap wanted targets overseas, with or without the host country’s permission.

Are there other reasonably confirmed examples where Chinese police renditions people back to China, seemingly without the involvement of local authorities (although possibly with their tacit approval) in the country where the arrest takes place?

Comment: FWTW, the piece also says "China and Mongolia have ratified a bilateral extradition treaty, but such requests typically involve lengthy procedures. There are no known extradition cases that have been carried out by the Mongolian government."

Comment: The word "arrest" suggests something lawful. The more appropriate word is "kidnap".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [Causeway Bay Books disappearances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causeway_Bay_Books_disappearances), [Gui Minhai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gui_Minhai) (a Swedish citizen) was "disappeared" while in Thailand; while Lui Bo, Lam Wing-kee, and Lee Bo were "disappeared" while in Hong Kong.

[Xiao Jianhua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiao_Jianhua) (Chinese and Canadian, also got a Antigua and Barbuda passport days before his "disappearance") was "disappeared" from Hong Kong in 2017.

[Wang Bingzhang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wang_Bingzhang_(dissident)) was "disappeared" from Viet Nam in 2002.

A Chinese diplomat Chen Yonglin who defected to Australia in 2005 [alleged](https://www.theage.com.au/national/chinese-diplomat-was-urged-not-to-defect-20050727-ge0l2x.html) that "spies kidnapped Lan Meng in 2000, to force the boy's father to return to China." Chen also alleged "that Chinese authorities had as many as 1000 spies in Australia who targeted dissidents and regularly kidnapped people."

[Li Xin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li_Xin_(journalist)) was "disappeared" in Thailand in 2016.

[Yang Zewei/Qiao Xinxin](https://www.rfa.org/english/news/china/china-subversion-08142023125713.html) was "disappeared" from Laos in 2023.

---

International Service for Human Rights ([2023](https://ishr.ch/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/SDISHR1.pdf)):

> In 2018, the National Supervision Law was adopted. An accompanying written legal interpretation ... formalized the techniques ...

> it includes the following special measures: ...

> "**An unconventional measure.** There are two kinds of common ones, (1) **kidnapping**, using the means of kidnapping to arrest the fugitives and return to China; (2) **trapping** or **lure** the suspect to the territory, the international high seas, the international airspace or a third country with an extradition treaty, and then [move for their] arrest or extradition."

Original version of the [last paragraph](https://www.ccdi.gov.cn/djfg/fgsy/201807/t20180704_175037.html):

> 非常规措施。比较常见的有两种，（1）绑架，采用绑架的手段将在逃人员缉捕回国；（2）诱捕，将犯罪嫌疑人引诱到诱骗国境内、国际公海、国际空域或有引渡条约的第三国，然后进行逮捕或引渡。由于未经主权国家的批准擅自开展调查活动，会触犯所在地国家刑事法律，构成非法拘禁罪或绑架罪，引发外交纠纷，因此，实践中，绑架或诱捕手段很少使用。

The last sentence was not included in International Service for Human Rights's translation. Here Google translated:

> Since conducting investigation activities without the approval of a sovereign country will violate the criminal laws of the country where the person is located, constitute the crime of illegal detention or kidnapping, and cause diplomatic disputes, therefore, in practice, kidnapping or entrapment methods are rarely used.